# Class initialization parens to use

Tags: c++, c++11

I wanted to initialize some class members and I get error
`"expected parameter declarator"` ( using clang++ )
while using g++ `"expected identifier before numeric constant".`
So I read again the class initializations and I write the code bellow:

```
#include <stdio.h>    
class AAA{
public:
    int l;
    AAA(int i){l=i;}
};

class BBB{
    bool normal;
    AAA aaa=10;
    AAA bbb(20);
    AAA ccc{30};
    AAA ddd={45};
};

int main(int argc, char **argv){printf("hello world\n");return 0;}
```

It seems that the syntax `AAA bbb(20)` isn't accepted !

Is this normal ? ( I use option -std=c++11 ).

Or I miss some point ?

Comment: use `AAA bbb{20};` too.

Answer (score 8):

This is normal. C++11 does not allow for `()` brackets in in-place initialization of non-static data members. This is to avoid potential parses as functions. You *could* use the `()` perantheses with this syntax:

```
AAA bbb = AAA(20);
```

because this form could not be parsed as a function.