# Creating objects as private class variables in C++

Tags: c++, class, oop, object

In my program I'd like to initialise an object from the OpenCV library as part of my own object. However, whenever I initialise it, I receive this error:

> error: expected parameter declarator

It works if I don't initialise the object with it's constructor, but I need to do this. Also, I'd like to be able to use this object's methods later on to modify it with new data. Below is a very simple example of the kind of code which is giving me the error.

```
class test
{
    public:
        test (int number);

    private:
        cv::LDA lda(2);
}
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [Class initialization parens to use](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21215609/class-initialization-parens-to-use)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you use c++11 then you can initialize at the same time you declare:

```
class test {
  public:
    test (int number);
  private:
    cv::LDA lda{2};
};
```

If not, then you must use member initialization in ctor definition:

```
class test {
  public:
    test (int number) : lda(2 /*or number?*/) {…};
  private:
    cv::LDA lda;
};
```

Comment: This doesn't explain why `lda(2)` doesn't work in the member declaration.

Comment: because it's a declaration not a definition.

Answer (score 2):

You can use either `=` or `{}`:

```
cv::LDA lda = cv::LDA(2);

// or

cv::LDA lda{2};
```

`()` can't be used for in-class member initialization because the it could then be interpreted as a function declaration in some cases.

Answer (score 2):

It would be better if you called lda's constructor from test's constructor. I think that if you don't initialize lda its default constructor is called.

Answer (score 1):

Please use C++ Constructors and member initializer lists http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/initializer_list

Basically, by using initializer lists, you can specify how your members are constructed.

```
class test
{
public:
    test (int number);

private:
    cv::LDA lda;
};

test::test(int number) : lda(2) { }
```